# What is a word or phrase to describe a forced smile from someone who is not practiced in smiling?

Tags: synonyms

I'm trying to think of a word to describe a forced smile by a person who feels no joy, but is trying to be friendly. I am imagining Clint Eastwood's character from Gran Torino.  What would be a good word for his half-grimace, half-smile?

Comment: Maybe stilted?  .  .

Comment: "He gave a sardonic look."

Answer (score 1):

I would call such a smile a ***"Pan Am smile"***.

> [The Pan Am smile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smile), aka the 'Botox smile," is the name given to a fake smile, in which only the zygomatic major muscle is voluntarily contracted to show politeness. It is named after the airline Pan American World Airways which went out of business in 1991, whose flight attendants would always flash every jet setter the same perfunctory smile.